# Geometry Conversion Problem

Tags: arcobjects, convert, geometry

How do I convert from an ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint to an ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic point object?

In other words, I'm wanting to convert from an IGeometry to a runtime geometry, I guess.

Comment: Are you working in SilverLight? Have you looked at the sample given here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic.html

Comment: Yes, actually I've been looking at this link this morning, but couldn't really pin-point my answer.  I'll take another look at it.  Maybe I'm just missing something.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are working in the Silverlight API, you won't have an IPoint. That exists only in the ArcObjects API. In silverlight, you will have a MapPoint. The linked page, shows how you can make a graphic from a MapPoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this with the following code snippit . . .

```c#
       //  *********************   Convert from IGeometry to runtime geometry    *********************
       // Create a new instance of one Graphic.
       ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic aGraphic = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic();

       // Create a SpatialReference for the Graphic. Point Graphics are known as MapPoint objects
       ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference aSpatialReference = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference(4326);
       // Create a MapPoint object and set its SpatialReference and coordinate (X,Y,Z) information. 
       ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.MapPoint aMapPoint = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.MapPoint();
       aMapPoint.SpatialReference = aSpatialReference;
       aMapPoint.X = Point.X;// Point is an IPoint object
       aMapPoint.Y = Point.Y;
       aMapPoint.Z = Point.Z;

       // Create a new instance of a SimpleMarkerSymbol and set its Style, and Size Properties.
       ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.SimpleMarkerSymbol aSimpleMarkerSymbol = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
       aSimpleMarkerSymbol.Style = ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.SimpleMarkerSymbol.SimpleMarkerStyle.Circle;
       aSimpleMarkerSymbol.Size = 10;

        // Apply the Graphic's Geometry and Symbol Properties.
       aGraphic.Geometry = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Geometry)aMapPoint;
       aGraphic.Symbol = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.Symbol)aSimpleMarkerSymbol;

       _graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(aGraphic);
```